# How to resize the plots to fit values in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am trying to plot a series of small values through scatter plot on Raspberry Pi 3B. But when ever I try to plot those values they appear very small. I have tried out `tight_layout()` and `axis('scaled')` on both figure level and plot level, but nothing seems to work.

**Code**

```
u_lat, u_lon, u_list = [], [], [i for i in range(200)]
        for i in range(200):
            u_lat.append(random.uniform(17.160541, 17.161970))
            u_lon.append(random.uniform(78.658089, 78.660843))

        ##############################################################
        # Scatter plot of data
        userDataPlotFig, ax = plt.subplots()

        ax.scatter(u_lat, u_lon)
```

**Plot Output**
[image]

I want it to be scaled properly to fit all the values on the screen.

Comment: It can't be reproduced. It scales correctly on my device.

Comment: "artificial-intelligence"

Comment: @Akella Niranjan try the option with limited axes suggested below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set x, y axis limits. I give an example in which the necessary limits of the axes are commented out. If you replace the current ones with the one in the comments you will see the difference.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.rand(70)
y = np.random.rand(70)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(x, y)
plt.xlim([0, 2])#plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.ylim([0, 3])#plt.ylim([0, 1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
plt.xlim([0, 2])
plt.ylim([0, 3])
```

[image]

```
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.ylim([0, 1])
```

In your example, I suggest doing the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

u_lat, u_lon, u_list = [], [], [i for i in range(200)]
for i in range(200):
    u_lat.append(np.random.uniform(17.160541, 17.161970))
    u_lon.append(np.random.uniform(78.658089, 78.660843))


lat = np.array(u_lat)
lon = np.array(u_lon)
min_x = np.min(lat)
max_x = np.max(lat)
min_y = np.min(lon)
max_y = np.max(lon)

userDataPlotFig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(u_lat, u_lon)
plt.xlim([min_x, max_x])
plt.ylim([min_y, max_y])
plt.show()
```